# How to reduce decryption time using AES in android

Tags: java, performance, encryption

I am now working on audio file encryption and decryption. It's working fine for me, but the decryption speed is too low. How to reduce the time of decryption? It should take <6 or 7 seconds. How can I do this? Please help me with an simple example. I am using AES.

Comment: Saying it should take less than 6 minutes is meaningless. You should specify a rate, in units of bytes per second (or megabytes per second, or some quantity per time units).

Comment: How fast is the decryption? You should be able to do several MB/s. You also need to post your code.

Comment: Sorry decryption should be completed in < 6 seconds.

Comment: @SriL How much data should be decrypted in 6 seconds? And are you sure your performance is limited by encryption, and not by IO?

Comment: I have to play the song without interruption, I have to start Playing the song in 6 seconds.There is no data limit to decrypt.We can decrypt it part by part.But I don't have any idea how to decrypt it part by part.Can I have a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a `javax.crypto.Cipher` instance. It can handle `update()` calls over arrays of arbitrary length, and you will need to reduce overhead if you use longer arrays.

Try should process data by blocks of, say, 8192 bytes (that's the traditional length for a buffer, it interacts reasonably well with CPU inner caches).

```
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, encipher);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Or larger (but use powers of 2)
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = cis.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
fos.flush();
```

....
Don't forget to close all streams in a finally block..

Comment: Thanks @ Frank .I am downloading the audio file from my server and have to encrypt with a key at the time of downloading and it should be saved in my sd card.When ever i want to paly the song the song it should be decrypt and play with in 6 seconds. Please help me with an example. .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EncryptDecrypt {
    public Cipher encryptcipher, decryptCipher;
    String TAG = "EncryptDecrypt";
    // The default block size
    public static int blockSize = 16;

    // Buffer used to transport the bytes from one stream to another
    byte[] buf = new byte[blockSize]; // input buffer
    byte[] obuf = new byte[8192]; // output buffer

    // The key
    byte[] key = null;  

     byte[] IV = null;

    public EncryptDecrypt(String passwd) {

        key = passwd.getBytes();
        key = "SECRETSECRET_1SE".getBytes();

        // default IV value initialized with 0
        IV = new byte[blockSize];
        initCiphers();

    }

    public void initCiphers() {
        try {
            // 1. create the cipher using Bouncy Castle Provider
            encryptcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
            // 2. create the key
            SecretKey keyValue = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            // 3. create the IV
            AlgorithmParameterSpec IVspec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
            // 4. init the cipher
            encryptcipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyValue, IVspec);
            encryptcipher.getOutputSize(8192);

            // 1 create the cipher
            decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
            // 2. the key is already created
            // 3. the IV is already created
            // 4. init the cipher
            decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyValue, IVspec);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String encryptData(URL inputFileName, String outputFileName) {
        File outFilename = new File(outputFileName);
        try {
            InputStream fis;
            OutputStream fos;
            fis = new BufferedInputStream(inputFileName.openStream(), 1000);
            fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));
            Log.i(TAG, "Output path:" + outFilename);
             int bufferLength = (inputFileName.toString().length() > 10000000
             ? 10000000
             : 1000);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int noBytes = 0;
            byte[] cipherBlock = new byte[encryptcipher
                    .getOutputSize(buffer.length)];

            int cipherBytes;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((noBytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                cipherBytes = encryptcipher.update(buffer, 0, noBytes,
                        cipherBlock);
                fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);
            }
            // always call doFinal
            cipherBytes = encryptcipher.doFinal(cipherBlock, 0);
            fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);
            System.out
                    .println("encryption "
                            + " took "
                            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0)
                            + "s");
            // close the files
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            Log.i("encrypt", "done");
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outFilename.toString().trim();
    }

    public String decryptData(String inputFileName, String outputFileName) {

        InputStream fis;
        OutputStream fos;
        try {
            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));
            fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int noBytes = 0;
            byte[] cipherBlock = new byte[decryptCipher
                    .getOutputSize(buffer.length)];
            int cipherBytes;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((noBytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                cipherBytes = decryptCipher.update(buffer, 0, noBytes,
                        cipherBlock);
                Log.d("BufferRead", "" + buffer);
                fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);
            }
            // allways call doFinal
            cipherBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(cipherBlock, 0);
            fos.write(cipherBlock, 0, cipherBytes);
            System.out
                    .println("decryption "
                            + " took "
                            + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0)
                            + "s");
            // close the files
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
            Log.i("decrypt", "done");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outputFileName.toString().trim();
    }
}

This is my code
```

Comment: If this is the code that doesn't work as you want, edit it into the question, and delete this. If it works, accept it.

Comment: It's working but it take lot of time to decrypt,I need to reduce the decryption time.